# Seleccionar codigo en dropdown y mostrar descripcion en TextBox JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Buenas,

Tengo un pequeño problema para mostrar resultados de datos de un proyecto.

Por un lado tengo una tabla en Mysql llamada OBRAS, con los campos CODIGO y DESCRIPCION.

En el HTML, tengo un dropdown list con buscador, en el que se muestran todos los codigos de obras que están abiertas, y tambien puedes buscarlas por codigo. Esto lo hago con Ajax y JSON.

Y por ultimo tengo un textbox bloqueado (disabled) donde quiero que se muestre la descripcion de la obra seleccionada en el dropdown list.

Pruebas.html:
Dropdown:

```
<select class="itemName form-control" style="width:500px" name="itemName" id="itemName"></select>
```

Textbox:

```
<p><input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="obranom" name="obranom"></p>
```

script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.itemName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecciona una obra',
        ajax: {
          url: 'ajaxpro.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data

            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });
</script>
```

ajaxpro.php:

```
<?php
define (DB_USER, "*****");
define (DB_PASSWORD, "*******");
define (DB_DATABASE, "******");
define (DB_HOST, "localhost");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$sql = "SELECT CODIGO, DESCRIPCION FROM obras 
        WHERE CODIGO LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%' AND ESTADO='Abierto'"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$json = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $json[] = ['id'=>$row['CODIGO'], 'text'=>$row['CODIGO']];

}

echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

Necesito mostrar la descripcion en el textbox "obranom" del codigo seleccionado en el dropdown "itemName"

Gracias de antemano y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
var texto= $("#itemName:selected").val();
$("#obranom").val(texto);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Aritz Ezkiaga, pero no funciona...